# .NET 6 Build Hangs When Running "npm start" using MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to automate starting my Angular/TypeScript development server whenever I build my .NET 6 project. I've added an MSBuild target to execute `npm start` before the build, but the .NET build process gets stuck in an endless loop because `npm start` runs continuously.

Here's my current .csproj setup:

```xml
<Target Name="RunNpmStart" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm start" />
</Target>
```

How can I modify this approach to execute `npm start` without blocking the .NET build? Ideally, is there a way to persist the Angular/TypeScript development server across .NET project builds, avoiding unnecessary restarts when I initiate the build process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about trying with CMD's `start`? https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: You may want to look into orchestrating your local dev setup with .NET Aspire - see this example for running APIs and Frontends: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/aspire-samples/aspire-angular-react-vue/ - this is meant primarily for .NET 8+ though

Comment: For .NET 6/7: You can look into the SPA templates (`dotnet new angular`) to see how an integrated setup can work where the backend launches the frontend dev server for development using the SpaProxy middleware / hostingstartup